# Difficulty deploying lumen app

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to deploy a small application to my remote server, however, I seem to be having difficulty with some of the routes.  Bare in mind that everything works on my local machine.

Here is what I've done:

1. Uploaded the entire project to `/home/user/app`
2. Moved contents of `/home/user/app/public` to `/home/user/public_html/api`
3. Modified `/home/user/public_html/api/index.php` from:

`$app->run();`

to

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);
```

...this allowed my first route to work, but I cannot load any other routes such as:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/api/v1/book`

Please note that only `http://www.mywebsite.com/api` is the only route that loads correctly.

My routes.php looks like this:

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    return "Lumen RESTful API";
});

$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1','namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function($app)
{
    $app->get('book','BookController@index');

    $app->get('book/{id}','BookController@getbook');

    $app->post('book','BookController@createBook');

    $app->put('book/{id}','BookController@updateBook');

    $app->delete('book/{id}','BookController@deleteBook');
});
```

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The error I am receiving:

[image: The error I am receiving]

Let me know if you need any more information?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tied changing the route prefix `$app->group(['prefix' => 'v1'`

Comment: Oh hey Andy @AngadDubey small world ;) That worked! Cheers!

Comment: Hey man, i thought I recognized that dp. gonna answer the question -- gimme dem points

Comment: @AngadDubey roger that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change route group prefix to:

`$app->group(['prefix' => 'v1'`